# Combining ui.bootstrap and mgcrea.ngStrap - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am combining `ui.bootstrap` and `mgcrea.ngStrap` in my `angular` project. Only one seems to work (The last).

How do I use both?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'localytics.directives', 'datePicker', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages', 'aa.formExtensions', 'aa.notify', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use bot in one of my projects, but there seems at the moment some naming collisions, what I dit, is to make references only to those parts of ngStrap which I used, i.e.:

```
  angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap','mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.popover'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Both can work as long as your using element or attribute level their directive. But you can't use bootstrap.js as it collides with two other for event listening. I have used both and not faced any problem like that.